# QGIS KML to DJI Pilot 2 for Flight Route

Tags: dji, smartphone-app

I am unable to import KML polygon layers I generated in QGIS in DJI Pilot 2 on my DJI remote. I get the following error:

```
Attempt to invoke interface method java.util.iterator java.util.List.iterator()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this post](https://forum.dji.com/thread-283890-1-1.html), this solution works great:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <Style id="transBluePoly">
      <LineStyle>
        <width>1.5</width>
      </LineStyle>
      <PolyStyle>
        <color>7dff0000</color>
      </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <Placemark>
      <name>QGISexport</name>
      <styleUrl>#transBluePoly</styleUrl>
      <Polygon>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>
Copy here and remove this text            </coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

To automate this process for regular workflows, I wrote [this script](https://github.com/CharlesLehnen/QGIS_KML_to_DJI_Pilot_2) which makes the process super fast for many KML files.